# Some javascript statements not working at all with IIS 7 and Windows 2008

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, windows, iis-7

I have the following code working fine with Win 2003 & IIS 6:

```
javascript:window.opener.document.formConfirmation.textBoxDateFrom.value = '01/01/2011';
```

However it does not work with Win 2008 with IIS 7!

I cannot change the code above since the logic is populated from a calendar DLL that I have no access to.  I would like to know if it is a setting in IIS that restricts some of the Javascript on working. And if so, what can I do to make the code above work like before.

FYI, the following does **NOT work in IIS 7**:

```
document.Form1.txtAlias.value;
```

but this statement **WORKS in IIS 7**:

```
document.getElementById('txtAlias').value;
```

**while BOTH work with IIS 6** !!! What is that about? Any help will help me regain some of my hours wasted on this...

Comment: Charlako, I suspect you are confusing IIS (the web server that pushes down the HTML and JS to the browser) with the browser itself. The code above you are talking about... does it run inside a webpage ("in the browser")?  Or does it run on the server as if it was embedded inside an ASP page?  Do you know the difference? What browsers are you testing with?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have hard code the control names, but this names are probably dynamic render by asp.net. I say probably because you can setup them to not dynamic change the name on render.

Change your control id with **<%=Control.ClientID%>** or use some other method to get the values of your controls.

For example.

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtAlias.ClientID%>').value
```

or

```
javascript:window.opener.document.<%=Form.ClientID%>.<%=textBoxDate.ClientID%>.value = '01/01/2011';
```

In this part of your code `document.Form1.txtAlias.value;`, probably the `Form1` has change name and not the txtAlias.

- Other posible solution if you use asp.net version 4, is to use static id names on your controls.
- a tip, on your pages, on your web browser, make right click | view source code to see how your control renders (what id they get).